# Using VHDL generic values in other generics

Tags: vhdl

I want to be able to specify a number of channels as a generic and use this to specify the range of an array containing further parameters. When compiling, my Aldec compile tell me that 'num_chan' cannot be referenced until the interface list is complete.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

```
ENTITY deframer IS
    generic (
      num_chan : integer                      := 2;            
      ch_low   : int_arr(num_chan-1 downto 0) := (  1, 189);   
      ch_hi    : int_arr(num_chan-1 downto 0) := (127, 189));
```

Comment: Note that the language allows you to use unconstrained arrays here.  If you are doing synthesis, your synthesis tool may not - you will have to try it.

Answer (score 5):

In VHDL-2002 (and earlier), a formal generic declared within a given generic
list can't be used to declared other generics in that list, which is the
reason for the error you see.

In VHDL-2008 that is possible, so if the required tools support VHDL-2008 and
that feature ("Referencing generics in generic lists"), then you can indicate
to the tools that VHDL-2008 is used.

A solution for VHDL-2002, is to make the `ch_low` and `ch_hi` arrays large
enough to accommodate any value of `num_chan`, and then fill the unused with a
dummy value, like (assuming `num_chan` is at most 10, using -1 as dummy value):

```
generic(
  num_chan : integer            := 2;
  ch_low   : int_arr_t(1 to 10) := (  1, 189, others => -1);
  ch_hi    : int_arr_t(1 to 10) := (127, 189, others => -1));
```